# Actions-On-Google NodeJS v2 alpha: More than one conv.close()

Tags: actions-on-google

Will we be able to use conv.close() multiple times within an intent to provide more than just a single element on exit?

Similar to how you can provide multiple conv.ask() in the one intent.

Or can you include more than one 'new element' in a conv.close() tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course to both ways! At least it's how it works currently during the alpha (which can change depending on feedback).

`conv.ask` and `conv.close` are [implemented almost identically](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/c84ba000b6257b4d932e022658405e8661524625/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.ts#L139) just that `conv.close` sets `expectUserResponse` to `false` which means you don't expect more responses from the user and the mic will be closed.

This means you can use `conv.close` just like `conv.ask` and call it multiple times.

For example, this code:

```es6
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')

const app = dialogflow()

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.close(`Here's a cat image`)
  conv.close(new Image({
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/' +
      'semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg',
    alt: 'A Cat',
  }))
})
```

when the `IntentHandler` function is done executing (or if it returns a `Promise`, when the `Promise` is resolved), constructs a `RichResponse` based on the response fragments you provided and sends it back to Dialogflow or the Google Assistant.

It closes the mic and shows this as a result in the simulator.

[image: Actions on Google Simulator Multiple Close Screenshot]

Alternatively, `conv.ask` and `conv.close` also allow you to call it with an arbitrary number of response arguments. So this code will also work identical to the example before:

```es6
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.close(`Here's a cat image`, new Image({
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/' +
      'semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg',
    alt: 'A Cat',
  }))
})
```